# Notepad++ - Replace with adds a new-line character after. How do I remove it?

Tags: notepad++

Original text:

```
2###
Test 123
```

I am doing this operation:

```
Find what: 2###
Replace with: 2###\r\nText before
```

Result:

```
2###
Text before
Test 123
```

Desired result:

```
2###
Text before Test 123
```

For some reason it adds a new-line after the replaced text. It seem to only happen when I add \r\n or \n in the Replace with.

How can I set it up so it does not insert this newline?

Comment: Try `Find what: 2###\r\n` instead of `Find what: 2###` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The replace is not adding an extra `\r\n` it is already there in the file.

The original text is:

```
2###\r\nTest 123
```

The effect of the find what of `2###` and replace with `2###\r\nText before` is to remove the piece that is found, leaving:

```
\r\nTest 123
```

Then adding the replace with text, giving:

```
2###\r\nText before\r\nTest 123
```

which is three lines in length.